# programmatically scroll PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, scroll, preferenceactivity

I have `PreferenceActivity` with plenty of `PreferenceCategories` defined in it. If I have the `android:key` of a given category.

Is it possible programmatically to scroll the `Activity` to this category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through the preferences in the activity like this:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
int i;
for(i = 0; i < screen.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
   String key = screen.getPreference(i).getKey();

   // be careful, because key will be null if no android:key is specified
   // (as is often the case for PreferenceCategory elements)
   if("myKey".equals(key))
      break;
}

// PreferenceActivity extends ListActivity, so the ListView is accessible...
getListView().setSelection(i);
```

Tested out with Android SDK 14 and it works fine.

*Caution though*, calling `getListView().setSelection(i)` inside onCreate or onResume has no effect.  It has to be called after the activity is drawn.

The getPreferenceCount() method counts all PreferenceCategories and their nested preferences.  Not sure what it does for PreferenceScreens, although I'm sure a little experimentation there would be revealing.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old answered question, but I found a better way than iterating through all the categories.

```
PreferenceCategory myCat = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("myKey");
int position = myCat.getOrder();
getListView().setSelection(position);
```